# Redis on Heroku not respond

Tags: redis, redis-py, heroku-redis

I'm pretty new to Redis queuing job task. I tried to do some function on the queue by using Redis To Go Add-on. But after I push some task on queue it seems to disappear.

Here is my code

```
import Flask
import redis
from rq import Queue

REDIS_URL = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', None)
if REDIS_URL!=None:
    r = redis.from_url(REDIS_URL)
else:
    r = redis.Redis()

q = Queue(connection=r)

def function(pam1):
    print("Checkpoint1")
    return 0

@main.route('/name', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def displayname():
    job = q.enqueue(function, pam1=0)
    return job.id
```

Additional info on queue: There still give the job id eg.7344337b-cca0-442a-b43a-abcdc88f012c.

but no sign of "Checkpoint1" on heroku log at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @v25. The real reason that Redis not responds because I don't have a WORKER. After get thu [see the Heroku guide on launching a worker](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq#create-a-worker) now my problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Heroku's logging implementation, but assuming you're looking at the wrong log (or something) you could try this...

Instead of printing 'Checkpoint', increment the value of a custom redis key:

```
def function(pam1):
    r.incr('job_ran', 1)
    return 0
```

Then create a route where you can check this value:

```
@app.route('/show_count')
def show_count():
    n = r.get('job_ran')

    if n is None:
        n = 0
    else:
        n = n.decode('utf-8')

    return f'Job has run {n} times'
```

Now enqueue a few jobs, and check the `/show_count` route to make sure it has incremented accordingly.

Comment: It said "Job has run None times" btw I did adapt code from you just a little bit because it seems to cause an error Nontype can't use decode. So I use '''n = str(r.get('job_ran'))''' instead.

Comment: Of course! `r.get` will return `None` if the key does not exist, which is the case before a job has sucessfully completed.  See my edit to account for this.

Comment: @MaitreeHirunteeyakun However are you saying even with this fix, the job does not run?  Other things to try: are you sure you've launched the worker?

Comment: (see the heroku guide on [launching a worker](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq#create-a-worker))

Comment: Yes, I forgot to make a worker.py Thx for helping so much!